# Syncfusion Rich Text Editor in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syncfusion

I'm trying to implement the Syncfusion rich text editor reactjs widget in my site. I've slightly modified the [demo code](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/bootstrap4/rich-text-editor/tools) to be a standalone class like this:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { addClass, removeClass, Browser } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { RichTextEditorComponent, Toolbar, Inject, Image, Link, HtmlEditor, Count, QuickToolbar, Table } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-richtexteditor';
import { createElement } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import * as CodeMirror from 'codemirror';
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';
import 'codemirror/mode/css/css.js';
import 'codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js';

class RichTextEd extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Rich Text Editor items list
        this.items = ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'StrikeThrough',
            'FontName', 'FontSize', 'FontColor', 'BackgroundColor',
            'LowerCase', 'UpperCase', '|',
            'Formats', 'Alignments', 'OrderedList', 'UnorderedList',
            'Outdent', 'Indent', 'SuperScript', 'SubScript', '|',
            'CreateTable', 'CreateLink', 'Image', '|', 'ClearFormat', 'Print',
            'SourceCode', 'FullScreen', '|', 'Undo', 'Redo'
        ];
        //Rich Text Editor ToolbarSettings
        this.toolbarSettings = {
            items: this.items
        };
    }

    mirrorConversion(e) {
        this.textArea = this.rteObj.contentModule.getEditPanel();
        let id = this.rteObj.getID() + 'mirror-view';
        let mirrorView = this.rteObj.element.querySelector('#' + id);
        let charCount = this.rteObj.element.querySelector('.e-rte-character-count');
        if (e.targetItem === 'Preview') {
            this.textArea.style.display = 'block';
            mirrorView.style.display = 'none';
            this.textArea.innerHTML = this.myCodeMirror.getValue();
            charCount.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            if (!mirrorView) {
                mirrorView = createElement('div', { className: 'e-content' });
                mirrorView.id = id;
                this.textArea.parentNode.appendChild(mirrorView);
            }
            else {
                mirrorView.innerHTML = '';
            }
            this.textArea.style.display = 'none';
            mirrorView.style.display = 'block';
            this.renderCodeMirror(mirrorView, this.rteObj.value);
            charCount.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    renderCodeMirror(mirrorView, content) {
        this.myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(mirrorView, {
            value: content,
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: 'text/html',
            lineWrapping: true,
        });
    }
    handleFullScreen(e) {
        let sbCntEle = document.querySelector('.sb-content.e-view');
        let sbHdrEle = document.querySelector('.sb-header.e-view');
        let leftBar;
        let transformElement;
        if (Browser.isDevice) {
            leftBar = document.querySelector('#right-sidebar');
            transformElement = document.querySelector('.sample-browser.e-view.e-content-animation');
        }
        else {
            leftBar = document.querySelector('#left-sidebar');
            transformElement = document.querySelector('#right-pane');
        }
        if (e.targetItem === 'Maximize') {
            if (Browser.isDevice && Browser.isIos) {
                addClass([sbCntEle, sbHdrEle], ['hide-header']);
            }
            addClass([leftBar], ['e-close']);
            removeClass([leftBar], ['e-open']);
            if (!Browser.isDevice) {
                transformElement.style.marginLeft = '0px';
            }
            transformElement.style.transform = 'inherit';
        }
        else if (e.targetItem === 'Minimize') {
            if (Browser.isDevice && Browser.isIos) {
                removeClass([sbCntEle, sbHdrEle], ['hide-header']);
            }
            removeClass([leftBar], ['e-close']);
            if (!Browser.isDevice) {
                addClass([leftBar], ['e-open']);
                transformElement.style.marginLeft = leftBar.offsetWidth + 'px';
            }
            transformElement.style.transform = 'translateX(0px)';
        }
    }
    actionCompleteHandler(e) {
        if (e.targetItem && (e.targetItem === 'SourceCode' || e.targetItem === 'Preview')) {
            this.rteObj.sourceCodeModule.getPanel().style.display = 'none';
            this.mirrorConversion(e);
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(() => { this.rteObj.toolbarModule.refreshToolbarOverflow(); }, 400);
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (<div className='control-pane'>
            <div className='control-section' id="rteTools">
                <div className='rte-control-section'>
                    <RichTextEditorComponent id="toolsRTE" ref={(richtexteditor) => { this.rteObj = richtexteditor; }} showCharCount={true} actionBegin={this.handleFullScreen.bind(this)} actionComplete={this.actionCompleteHandler.bind(this)} maxLength={2000} toolbarSettings={this.toolbarSettings}>
                        <div>
                            <p>The Rich Text Editor is WYSIWYG ("what you see is what you get") editor useful to create and edit content, and return the valid <a href='https://ej2.syncfusion.com/home/' target='_blank'>HTML markup</a> or <a href='https://ej2.syncfusion.com/home/' target='_blank'>markdown</a> of the content</p> <p><b>Toolbar</b></p><ol><li> <p>Toolbar contains commands to align the text, insert link, insert image, insert list, undo/redo operations, HTML view, etc</p></li><li><p>Toolbar is fully customizable </p></li></ol> <p><b>Links</b></p><ol><li><p>You can insert a hyperlink with its corresponding dialog </p></li><li><p>Attach a hyperlink to the displayed text. </p></li><li><p>Customize the quick toolbar based on the hyperlink </p> </li></ol><p><b>Image.</b></p><ol><li><p>Allows you to insert images from an online source as well as the local computer </p> </li><li><p>You can upload an image</p></li><li><p>Provides an option to customize quick toolbar for an image</p></li></ol><img alt="Logo" src="https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/src/rich-text-editor/images/RTEImage-Feather.png" style={{ width: '300px' }}/>
                        </div>
                        <Inject services={[Toolbar, Image, Link, HtmlEditor, Count, QuickToolbar, Table]}/>
                    </RichTextEditorComponent>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}

export default RichTextEd;
```

I'm then using it in my component with

```
<RichTextEd />
```

The editor doesn't render as expected, and there's an error reported about the `ref` being used in strict mode:

```
Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of RichTextEditorComponent which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.
```

I think I understand that the problem is with the way the `ref` is set in the `render` method, but I'm unclear on where the `this.rteObj` is defined initially, and further how to make this work as expected from a parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion support,

We have tried the shared code blocks of the RichTextEditor rendered from parent component, which works fine and we haven't faced any issues. Can you please check the below working example.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-render-parent-component?file=index.js